# How to label the vertical lines independent of the scale of the plot?

Tags: python, matplotlib, text

My program takes `n` sets of data and plots their histograms.

### I. How to label the vertical lines independent of the height of the plot?

A vertical line indicates the most frequent value in a dataset. I want to add a label indicating the value, say 20% from the top. When using `matplotlib.pyplot.text()` I had to manually assign `x` and `y` values. **Depending up on the dataset the text goes way up or way down which I don't want to happen.**

```
matplot.axvline(most_common_number, linewidth=0.5, color='black')
matplot.text(most_common_number + 3, 10, str(most_common_number),
    horizontalalignment='center', fontweight='bold', color='black')
```

I also tried setting the `label` parameter of `matplotlib.pyplot.axvline()` but it only adds to the `legend` of the plot.

`matplot.axvline(most_common_number, linewidth=0.5, color='black', label=str(most_common_number))`

[image]

**I wonder if there is a way to use percentages so the text appears `n%` from the top or use a different method to label the vertical lines. Or am I doing this all wrong?**

### II. How to make the ticks on x-axis to be spaced out better on resulting image?

I want the x-axis ticks to be factors of 16 so I had to override the defaults. This is where the trouble began. When I save the plot to a PNG file, the x-axis looks really messed up.

[image: The ticks on the x-axis need to be spaced out better]

But when I use `show()` it works fine:
[image]

#### Program Snippet

```
kwargs = dict(alpha=0.5, bins=37, range=(0, 304), density=False, stacked=True)
fig, ax1 = matplot.subplots()

colors = ['tab:blue', 'tab:orange', 'tab:green', 'tab:red', 'tab:purple', 'tab:brown', 'tab:pink', 'tab:gray', 'tab:olive', 'tab:cyan']

count = 0
'''
datasets = [('dataset name', ['data'])]
'''
for item in datasets:
    dataset = item[1]
    most_common_number = most_common(dataset)
    ax1.hist(dataset, **kwargs, label=item[0], color=colors[count])
    matplot.axvline(most_common_number, linewidth=0.5, color='black')
    matplot.text(most_common_number + 3, 10, str(most_common_number),
        horizontalalignment='center', fontweight='bold', color='black')
    count += 1

#for x-axis
loc = matplotticker.MultipleLocator(base=16) # this locator puts ticks at regular intervals
ax1.xaxis.set_major_locator(loc)
#for y-axis
y_vals = ax1.get_yticks()
ax1.set_yticklabels(['{:3.1f}%'.format(x / len(datasets[0][1]) * 100) for x in y_vals])

#set title
matplot.gca().set(title='1 vs 2 vs 3')
#set subtitle
matplot.suptitle("This is a cool subtitle.", va="bottom", family="overpass")

matplot.legend()

fig = matplot.gcf()
fig.set_size_inches(16, 9)

matplot.savefig('out.png', format = 'png', dpi=120)
matplot.show()
```

Comment: What's the question? Seems you know the solution already?

Comment: I don't know the solution for the first part. The arbitrary `x`, `y` values I give for `matplotlib.text()` doesn't hold for all datasets. Sometimes the plot is scaled in such a way that the text goes way up or way down, sometimes even invisible! @ImportanceOfBeingErnest

Comment: Ah ok. What exactly do you mean by *n%*? Percent of what? The value of the bin within which the annotation occurs?

Comment: If the height of the plot is 100, I want the text beside the vertical lines to be at say 80. The problem is for one graph the value is 80 but for another graph the value is 240. Is there a way to tell the text to be always displayed at 80% the height of the plot no matter how big or small the plot is due to the values of the dataset?

Comment: Ah, % of the height of the plot is easy. `ax.text(most_common_number, 0.8, "text", transform=ax.get_xaxis_transform())`

Comment: This is it! This works for me. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### I. How to label the vertical lines independent of the height of the plot?

It can be done in two ways:

*Axes limits*

[matplotlib.pyplot.xlim](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.xlim.html) and [matplotlib.pyplot.ylim](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.ylim.html)

`ylim()` will give the max and min values of the axis. eg: `(0.0, 1707.3)`

```
matplot.text(x + matplot.xlim()[1] * 0.02 , matplot.ylim()[1] * 0.8,
        str(most_common_number),,
        horizontalalignment='center', fontweight='bold', color='black')
```

`(x + matplot.xlim()[1] * 0.02` means at `x` but 2% to the right. Because you don't want the text to coincide on the vertical line it labels.

`matplot.ylim()[1] * 0.8` means at 80% height of the y-axis.

Or you can directly specify `x` and `y` as scale (eg: 0.8 of an axis) using [transform](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/text_api.html?highlight=text#matplotlib.text.Text) parameter:

```
matplot.text(most_common_number, 0.8,
    '        ' + str(most_common_number), transform=ax1.get_xaxis_transform(),
    horizontalalignment='center', fontweight='bold', color='black')
```

Here `y = 0.8` means at 80% height of y-axis.

### II. How to make the ticks on x-axis to be spaced out better on resulting image?

Use `matplotlib.pyplot.gcf()` to change the dimensions and use a custom `dpi` (otherwise the text will not scale properly) when saving the figure.

`gcf()` means "[get current figure](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.gcf.html)".

```
fig = matplot.gcf()
fig.set_size_inches(16, 9)
matplot.savefig('out.png', format = 'png', dpi=120)
```

So the resulting image will be (16*120, 9*120) or (1920, 1080) px.